# Troca de informações com fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tenho um CRUD para adicionar usuários mas estou com dificuldade para implementar o editar. 
O usuário ao clicar em editar queria que o edittext fosse carregado já preenchido.

Para isso, tentei implementar algo do tipo:

```
ImageView editarBt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.editar);
            editarBt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("nome", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNome());
                    data.putString("email", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getEmail());
                    data.putString("np", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNp());
                    data.putString("tipoFunc", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getTipoFunc());
                    data.putInt("id", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getId());
                    Fragment fragment = new adicionar_usuario();
                    fragment.setArguments(data);
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,fragment, fragment.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();


                }
            });
```

Ou seja, quando o usuário clicar no ícone para editar, queria que tela já viesse com as informações carregadas para dar o update.

Consegui isso através do intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), adicionar_usuario.class);
                manager.putFragment(bundle,"nome", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNome());
                intent.putExtra("email", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getEmail());
                intent.putExtra("np", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNp());
                intent.putExtra("tipoFunc", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getTipoFunc());
                intent.putExtra("id", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getId());
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Mas como é um fragment, o intent não se torna viável.

E no meu fragment que quero que seja carregado a informação (adicionar_usuario), com o intent é:

```
 Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    if(intent != null){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){

            usuario.setId(bundle.getInt("id"));
            usuario.setNome(bundle.getString("nome"));
            usuario.setEmail(bundle.getString("email"));
            usuario.setTipoFunc(bundle.getString("tipoFunc"));
            usuario.setNp(bundle.getString("np"));

            nomeEt.setText(usuario.getNome());
            emailEt.setText(usuario.getEmail());
            npEt.setText(usuario.getNp());
            tipoFuncSp.toString();

          //  senhaEt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            salvarBt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editarUserBt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    }
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Talvez este link possa te ajudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, veja que no onClickListener você está passando um Bundle como Arguments pra fragment:

```
fragment.setArguments(data);
```

Então na fragment você tem que ler dos arguments. Faça no método onViewCreated da sua fragment a leitura pegando com getArguments();

```
getArguments().getString("nome", "");
getArguments().getString("email", "");
getArguments().getString("np", "");
getArguments().getString("tipoFunc", "");
getArguments().getInt("id", 0);
```

Comment: Mas como eu pego esse bundle e verifico se ele está preenchido? com o intent eu faria assim: `Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if(intent != null){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle != null){`

Comment: getArguments volta um Bundle. É só você verificar se ele tem alguma coisa, da forma if(getArguments() != null) {}, ai dentro do brace do if você pega da forma que eu passei os tipos. Referência: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()